# Simple responsive webpage assignment - paragraph boxes too big then too small

Tags: html, css, responsive

My page has three boxes with text in them.

At full size there is too much blank space in the boxes, but if I change the height or margins, there isn't enough space when the browser window gets smaller.

Can I link the text to the box so they get bigger and smaller together?

Should look like these:
[Desktop, tablet, and mobile browser sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zci7h.png)

[Mine looks like this:](https://jsfiddle.net/ntf79/nzyLyjxn/)
- too much space vertically between boxes in tablet view
- too much empty space in boxes at full size in each of the views

```css
********** Base styles **********/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font: 175% helvetica;
}

p {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 130px;
  /*margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;*/
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  padding: 50px 12px 75px 20px;
  font-size: 125%;
}

#p1 {
  margin-left: 13px;
  margin-right: 13px;
}

#p2 {
  margin-left: 13px;
  margin-right: 13px;
}

#p3 {
  margin-left: 13px;
  margin-right: 13px;
}

body { 
  margin-left: 26px;
  margin-right: 26px;
  padding:0;
}
#label1 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 120px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: none;
  border-top: none;
  background-color: #ff6666;
  padding: 10px 10px 0px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: -276px;
  left: -14px;

}

#label2 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 120px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  background-color:  #ffffb3;
  padding: 10px 10px 0px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: -276px;
  left: -14px;
}

#label3 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 120px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  background-color:  #ff99ff;
  padding: 10px 10px 0px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: -276px;
  left: -14px;
}
/* Simple Responsive Framework. */
.row {
  width: 100%;
  
}

/********** DESKTOP **********/
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-lg-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/********** TABLET **********/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/********** MOBILE **********/
@media (max-width: 0px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-sm-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-sm-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="Simple restaurant webpage">
<meta name="keywords" content="restaurant">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
<title>Assignment 2</title>
</head>


<body>
<header>Our Menu</header>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12"><p id="p1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex</p><p id="label1">Beef</p></div>
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12"><p id="p2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex</p><p id="label2">Chicken</p></div>
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12"><p id="p3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex</p><p id="label3">Pork</p></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a set height for each box, which works for the desktop version, but not when you shrink it down.

Set each box height to **"auto"** instead of ***"130px"*** and adjust the padding on each box accordingly.

**Unrelated to your issue:** Also if you have elements that have the same attributes (#p1, #p2, #p3, #label1, #label2, #label3), you can just use a div class instead of an individual ID for each element. (view my codepen for reference: http://codepen.io/johndurso/pen/xgLZEw/)

## HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <header>Our Menu</header>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="title" style="background-color: #ff6666;">Chicken</div>
        <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, uis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="title" style="background-color: #ffffb3;">Beef</div>
        <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, uis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
        <div class="title" style="background-color: #ff99ff;">Pork</div>
        <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, uis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

## CSS:

```
header {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px 0;
  font: 28px helvetica;
}

div {
  position: relative;
}

p.description {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  padding: 50px 10px 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 10px;
    padding: 10px 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ff6666;
  text-align: center;
}

body { 
  margin: 0 26px;
  padding:0;
}
/* Simple Responsive Framework. */
.row {
  width: 100%;
}

/********** DESKTOP **********/
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-lg-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/********** TABLET **********/
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/********** MOBILE **********/
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-sm-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-sm-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-sm-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-sm-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's great.  One thing: the width of the chicken title is longer than the other two.  I'll play around with that.